# Identifying this form of sorting algorithm and calculating its time complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

While experimenting with sorting, I came up with a sort that seems to resemble some sort of insertion sort.

The difference would be that upon a swap, I'm not having to compare elements (worst-case) from element index up to index 0.

It also resembles something akin to a divide-and-conquer sorting algorithm in that it emulates a sorted sector and an unsorted one within the same array.

How I look at it is that initially I'll assign the current element as the first element.
Then I'll compare the current element to the next one. If current is greater, I swap the elements. Then I decrement so as to keep current index same.

Otherwise, I increment to advance current index.

This means my current will always be the most updated reference value. The other values that were compared are always lesser and sorted.

Please refer to the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printArray(int *a, int l)
{
    int i = 1;
    printf("[%d", a[0]);
    while(i < l)
    {
        printf(", %d", a[i]);
        ++i;
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

void whatSort(int *a, int l)
{
    int i = 0;
    int temp;

    while(i < (l - 1))
    {
        if(*(a + i) > *(a + i + 1))
        {
            temp = *(a + i);
            *(a + i) = *(a + i + 1);
            *(a + i + 1) = temp;
            --i;
        }
        else
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    //int array[] = {42, 18, 74, 2, 35, 92, 37, 25};
    int array[] = {6, 5, 3, 1, 8, 7, 2, 4};
    printArray(array, 8);
    whatSort(array, 8);
    printArray(array, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this sort of sort (pun intended) already exists, but I'm unable to find out the name. Would be great to know what it's called. Nevertheless, I would like assistance in calculating the runtime complexity of the piece of code for this sort only. This is what I've come up with. Any help would be much appreciated.

For this particular case, it is assumed that each operation takes 1 time unit.

```
Declaration
Assignment
Declaration

Loop condition will run l - 1 times:
    Comparison
    Subtraction

Loop inside code will run l - 2 times:
    IF statement:
        Dereference
            Addition
        Comparison
        Dereference
            Addition
            Addition
    Assignment
    Dereference
        Addition
    Dereference
        Addition
    Assignment
    Dereference
        Addition
        Addition
    Dereference
        Addition
        Addition
    Assignment
    Decrement

    OR

    ELSE statement:
        Increment
```

Ultimately, I'm coming up with O(n) where:

```
Worst case = 3 + [2 * (l - 1)] + [6 * (l - 2)] + [14 * (l - 2)]
    O(22n - 39)
    O(n)
Best case = 3 + [2 * (l - 1)] + [6 * (l - 2)] + (l - 2)
    O(9n - 13)
    O(n)
```

Comment: This is just a really slow insertion sort, so O(n^2). Worst case is an array that starts out in reverse order, e.g. `int array[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};` Every time `i` reaches the end of the sorted section of the array, the algorithm needs to carry the next number all the way back to the beginning of the array. That's the way insertion sort works, but insertion sort does it faster. Then the algorithm wastes a whole bunch of time going forward to find the end of the sorted section. Insertion sort keeps track of where the end of the sorted section is, and just jumps there.

Comment: I don't understand. The entire array is traversed once only there are no nested loops.

Comment: Even if there's a decrement each time, this amounts to an extra l - 2 steps.

Comment: Use the array I suggested. Put a `printf("%d\n", i);` at the top of the loop. Post the results here.

Comment: Output: 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: Could you please go over this with me?

Comment: I already did. `i` increments until it reaches the end of the sorted section. Then it decrements until it reaches the beginning of the array.

Comment: What are the errors I have made in my worst case calculation? Logically, I'm still trying to find out why it decrements so further back, since the adjacent values are compared, but the 'left' values had all been lesser.

Comment: Imagine the algorithm has progressed until the array is `[6,7,8,9,5,4,3,2,1]` and `i=3` and `array[i]` is the 9. Now the code compares 9 and 5, swaps them, and decrements `i`. So now `array[i]` is 8. Compare 8 and 5, swap them, and decrement `i`. The algorithm has to keep doing that until `i` is 0 because the 5 has to go at the beginning of the sorted section.

Comment: Ah yes. This has made things clearer. What did I do wrong in my worst-case calculation such that I did not get n ^ 2? Also, why don't you post as answer, you've really helped me work towards the answer.

Comment: Dennis Ritchie had a great idea when he decided that `*(a+i)` is to be written as `a[i]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but there are no sorting algorithms better than O(n log n), unless you put some restrictions to the input.

Currently this code does not work.

For example, if the first element is greater then the second (which is the case in your example), then `i` is decremented. Initially `i=0`, so now `i=-1`. The loop restarts, and you try to access `a[-1]`, and Segmentation fault occurs. The error is

> Then I decrement so as to keep current index same.

That`s not what happens, the index is decremented, as you said, so the value is not kept.

[This is the ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emPRa.png)

EDIT:

Even if this case is corrected, the following is not true

> Loop inside code will run l - 2 times:

The algorithm always tries to get (i+1)-th element to the correct position, bringing it at worst to the first position.

When `index == 0`, you make at most one swap.
When `index == 1`, you make at most two swaps.
When `index == 2`, you make at most three swaps.

This happens until you reach the end of the array.
So, 1x2x3x...x(n-1), which is O(n²)

Comment: The code works as intended. Either way, we are able to circumvent this issue by adding only decrementing if i != 0.

Comment: I showed another case. The point is: you need to assert the subarray from index 0 until `i` is sorted.

Comment: Hey thanks for going over the code. As I had mentioned, does this problem still persist if I only decrement if ```i != 0```?

Comment: Yes now that 20, 30, 10 is used, I see a segmentation error. I don't clearly understand it yet.

Comment: Ah nevermind that array length parameter has to be changed.

Comment: Yes, my friend, you forgot to change the second parameter of the sort function from 8 to 3.

Comment: For some reason, it is working fine on my end. ```i``` is increased, but the loop is ending at ```l - 2```.

Comment: Sorry, it does work, but it's O(n^2). The @user3386109 comment in your question explains it.

Comment: Would you kindly explain how I messed up my worst case calculation in your answer? Then I can mark it as the correct answer.